# error with read html tag attributes with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to read and list text in td based on data-property with beautifulsoup

```
 tr=BeautifulSoup(str(input),'lxml')
        tags=tr.findAll('td')
        for t in tags:      
            if t.attrs['data-property']== 'OSVersion':
               ver=t.text
```

this gives me error with no details

```
KeyError: 'data-property'
```

please see following as example tr extracted as input

```
<tr > 
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="OSVersion">10.2.1</td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="DisplayModel">iPad Mini 4 (64 GB Space Gray)</td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="PhoneNumber"></td>
<td class="grid_customvariable_colsize resizable reorderable" data-property="DeviceCustomAttributeDetails"></td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="DeviceTagDetails"></td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="EnrollmentStatusName">    <div class="grid_resizable_col">Enrolled</div>
</td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="ComplianceStatusName">    <div class="grid_resizable_col">Compliant</div>
</td>

<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="IMEI"></td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="LocationGroupName">iOS</td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="IsCompromisedYN">No</td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="HomeCarrier">Not Reported </td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="CurrentCarrier">Not Reported </td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="WiFiIPAddress"></td>

<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="Notes"></td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="WnsStatus">        <span>Disconnected</span>
</td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="DmLastSeenTime">    <span class="icon arrow_down_stretched red">-</span>
</td>                    
</tr>
```

and if i take single dict as following, it works fine

```
d={'class': ['', 'resizable', 'reorderable'], 'data-property': 'FriendlyName'}
print d['data-property']
```

anyone has idea how to fix it?

thanks

Comment: rename variable `str` in `BeautifulSoup` - it's a reserved word.

Comment: tried, thats not it, if thats the cause, it wont even run pass to next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, correct. We wrong.

**In ur code do following change because you got `KeyError`:**

`if 'data-property' in t.attrs and t.attrs['data-property']== 'OSVersion':`

**My answer for demo code:**

A `t.attrs` return list of tuples. e.g. `[(u'class', u' resizable reorderable'), (u'data-property', u'OSVersion')]`.

We need to convert to dictionary format by `dict` method . e.g. `attributes = dict(t.attrs)`

And in condition, check key is present or not. e.g. `if 'data-property' in attributes and attributes['data-property']== 'OSVersion':`

**Demo:**

```
import BeautifulSoup
tr = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(data)
tags = tr.findAll('td')
for t in tags:    
    attributes = dict(t.attrs)
    if 'data-property' in attributes and attributes['data-property']== 'OSVersion':
        ver = t.text
```

Let me know if you have still any issue(s). Free to ping me.

Comment: this actually worked, i checked all keys and it turns out there is one td has missing  data-property attr for unknown reason, once I added a line to test presence of this attr, it all worked, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

No need to mess with `attrs`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html = """<tr > 
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="OSVersion">10.2.1</td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="DisplayModel">iPad Mini 4 (64 GB Space Gray)</td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="PhoneNumber"></td>
<td class="grid_customvariable_colsize resizable reorderable" data-property="DeviceCustomAttributeDetails"></td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="DeviceTagDetails"></td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="EnrollmentStatusName">    <div class="grid_resizable_col">Enrolled</div>
</td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="ComplianceStatusName">    <div class="grid_resizable_col">Compliant</div>
</td>

<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="IMEI"></td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="LocationGroupName">iOS</td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="IsCompromisedYN">No</td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="HomeCarrier">Not Reported </td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="CurrentCarrier">Not Reported </td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="WiFiIPAddress"></td>

<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="Notes"></td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="WnsStatus">        <span>Disconnected</span>
</td>
<td class=" resizable reorderable" data-property="DmLastSeenTime">    <span class="icon arrow_down_stretched red">-</span>
</td>                    
</tr>"""

soup = BS(html)
tags=soup.findAll('td')
for t in tags:
    if t['data-property'] == 'OSVersion':
        ver=t.text
        print(ver)
```

output:

```
10.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.
Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("xmlfile.xml", "r") as f: # opening xml file
    content = f.read() # xml content stored in this variable
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
for values in soup.findAll("td"):
    if  values["data-property"] == "OSVersion":
        print values.text
```

Output :

```
10.2.1
```